# Exponentially increasing $\Omega(E)$

Tags: statistical-mechanics

If I choose the number of microstates for energy $E$ to be $\Omega(E) = e^{aE}$ ($a>0$), its temperature is constant:
$$
kT = \left( {d\ln \Omega \over dE} \right)^{-1} = 1/a
$$
If I choose $\Omega(E) = e^{aE^2}$ ($a>0$), its temperature decreases as the energy goes up:
$$
kT = \left( {d\ln \Omega \over dE} \right)^{-1} = {1 \over 2aE} 
$$
These pathological results seem to imply that something is problematic with
this kind of exponentially (or more) rapidly increasing $\Omega(E)$.  What prevents Nature to avoid such systems?  Or are such systems known to exist in reality?

Answer (score 1):

In string theory appears the so-called *Hagedorn behavior*, which is an exponential behavior of the density of states. As you point out, in this case, temperature does not vary with energy (so it means that the system has an infinite heat capacity!)

This behavior appears in Little String Theory, e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0010169.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. According to Blotzmann distribution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution , the number of microstates decreases as energy increase. If the number of microstates for energy you choose is right, then the stable state of the system  should have infinite energy, and it's impossible.

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. The Boltzmann distribution says that the *probability* of being in a state decreases as its energy increases, but this is not the same as the *number* of states with a given energy.